# Uncaught TypeError on second onclick event using this.innerHTML

Tags: typeerror

Everyone, I have a rather weird problem.

In an HMTL unordened list I have several list elements with onClick events, and they all call the same function.

```
<ul>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">1</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">2</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">3</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">4</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">5</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">6</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">7</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">8</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">9</li>
    <li onClick="Javascript:show(this.innerHTML); alert(this.innerHTML);">0</li>
</ul>
```

This is the Javascript function:

```
function show(ID){
    show = document.getElementById(ID);
    notShow = document.getElementsByClassName("visible")[0];
    if (typeof notShow !== "undefined"){
        notShow.classList.toggle("hidden");
        notShow.classList.toggle("visible");
    }               
    show.classList.toggle("hidden");
    show.classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

for some unknown reason, the function works fine when I click one of the `<li>` elements first, but the second time I do that I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function ACNL.php:31

I think the error is not inside the javaScript function, but in the HTML-element that calls the function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here. In no particular order:

- It would probably be safest to change the inner variable name `show` to something else since your function is also called `show(...)`.
- Declare variables with the `var` keyword to avoid populating the top namespace.
- You're retrieving DOM elements by ID, but none of your DOM elements (in the above example) have ID attributes. You'll want to add them to your `li` items at least, e.g. `id="1"`
- If these elements don't have `visible` to start off with, you'll add both `visible` and `hidden` when you "toggle".
- If you toggle `visible` and `hidden` on the `li` items, then `notShow = document.getElementsByClassName("visible")[0];` should probably change, as you will be retrieving the `li` items once they have `visible` in them. Try using other class names or element types.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X366Y/8/) to get you started (ignore the window.show definition that's specific to jsFiddle).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with the code was that I used show as a variable name and function name. Silly mistake! Also, thank you for your tips on improving the script in general.